# Cannot add ToolTip in style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, tooltip

I'm trying to add a `ToolTip` to a `Grid` using a `Style` (as follows):

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="ToolTipGrid" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}" x:Shared="False">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=Right}"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource KeyValueDataTemplate}" />
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=Left}"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource KeyValueDataTemplate}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ToolTip>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

However, at runtime I get the following error:

> Cannot add content of type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip' to
>   an object of type 'System.Object'. 
>   Error at object
>   'System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip' in
>   markup file
>   'InnoFit;component/controls/fittingdetails.xaml'
>   Line 24 Position 26.

What's wrong here?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796290/display-row-tooltip-in-wpf-datagrid) post successfully answers a similar problem.